# Why can't I catch ConnectionError after restarting telethon client event loop?

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I'm working on Telegram bot based on telethon library and trying to deal with `ConnectionError` exception which occurs if bot disconnected from the Internet. I want bot to restart after this error and the only solution I came up until now is to start bot's event loop in an infinite `while` loop. I'm trying to catch `ConnectionError` and stop bot's event loop if this error happens, so the `while` loop can run next iteration in which bot's event loop will be started again. The problem is I can do it only once. After restarting the event loop, then bot throws `ConnectionError` again it crushes the whole script.

Here is my code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

def error_catcher(loop, context):
    loop.stop()
    print('Exception catched: ', context)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = TelegramClient('test_session', api_id=os.environ['TG_API_ID'], api_hash=os.environ['TG_API_HASH'])
    bot.start(bot_token=os.environ['TG_BOT_TOKEN'])

    while True: 
        with bot:
            bot.loop.set_exception_handler(error_catcher)
            bot.loop.run_forever()
```

It successfully catches `ConnectionError` on first `while` iteration only, but on second one it crushes the whole script. Here is a fragment from stdout:

```
Attempt 1 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 2 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 3 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 4 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 5 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 6 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 1 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 2 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 3 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 4 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 5 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 6 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Automatic reconnection failed 5 time(s)
Exception catched:  {'message': 'Future exception was never retrieved', 'exception': ConnectionError('Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)'), 'future': <Future finished exception=ConnectionError('Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)')>}
Attempt 1 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 2 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 3 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 4 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 5 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Attempt 6 at connecting failed: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/notification_bot.py", line 175, in <module>
    with bot:
  File "/home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/helpers.py", line 219, in _sync_enter
    return loop.run_until_complete(self.__aenter__())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py", line 735, in __aenter__
    return await self.start()
  File "/home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py", line 141, in _start
    await self.connect()
  File "/home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 526, in connect
    if not await self._sender.connect(self._connection(
  File "/home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py", line 128, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "/home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py", line 254, in _connect
    raise ConnectionError('Connection to Telegram failed {} time(s)'.format(self._retries))
ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)
```

I don't understand why it's happening, especially since it seem to work fine with different exception. Here is a code snippet where I produce exception artificially:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

async def stopper():
    print('Started')
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
        raise ValueError
        

def error_catcher(loop, context):
    loop.stop()
    print('Exception catched: ', context)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = TelegramClient('test_session', api_id=os.environ['TG_API_ID'], api_hash=os.environ['TG_API_HASH'])
    bot.start(bot_token=os.environ['TG_BOT_TOKEN'])

    while True:
        with bot:
            bot.loop.create_task(stopper())
            bot.loop.set_exception_handler(error_catcher)
            bot.loop.run_forever()
```

And it works as I expect:

```
Started
Exception catched:  {'message': 'Task exception was never retrieved', 'exception': ValueError(), 'future': <Task finished name='Task-11' coro=<stopper() done, defined at /home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/notification_bot.py:147> exception=ValueError()>}
Started
Exception catched:  {'message': 'Task exception was never retrieved', 'exception': ValueError(), 'future': <Task finished name='Task-24' coro=<stopper() done, defined at /home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/notification_bot.py:147> exception=ValueError()>}
Started
Exception catched:  {'message': 'Task exception was never retrieved', 'exception': ValueError(), 'future': <Task finished name='Task-37' coro=<stopper() done, defined at /home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/notification_bot.py:147> exception=ValueError()>}
Started
Exception catched:  {'message': 'Task exception was never retrieved', 'exception': ValueError(), 'future': <Task finished name='Task-50' coro=<stopper() done, defined at /home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/notification_bot.py:147> exception=ValueError()>}
Started
Exception catched:  {'message': 'Task exception was never retrieved', 'exception': ValueError(), 'future': <Task finished name='Task-63' coro=<stopper() done, defined at /home/Sergey/PyProjects/sb/balance_bot/notification_bot.py:147> exception=ValueError()>}
```

Why I can't handle `ConnectionError` the same way? Any advises are appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error seems to hint the script cannot connect to Telegram at all. I recommend checking your network or perhaps configuring a proxy. You should also only stop the `loop` when you're done with it. If you keep reusing it, it will fail (so if you reuse it, don't stop it).

Comment: Don’t put “with” inside “while” because it closes down the client when “with” exits. Instead, create a new Client instance inside “while”.